# Invoking mercurial commands for all directories in a given directory

Tags: unix, mercurial

Let's say I have around 10 hg repositories cloned in a parent directory (let's call it "parent"). Is there any way I can invoke a mercurial command like `hg status` on all of the sub-directories rather than performing the laborious act of `cd`ing into each directory and then invoking `hg status`?

I did try out the good old `xargs` but for some reason it fails to work. The commands which I used are:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | xargs -t "hg status"
```

and

```
ls | xargs -t "hg status"
```

**Update:** the solution was to use explicit nameholders when using `xargs`. Something like:

```
ls | xargs -t -I {} hg status {}
```

Comment: Remove the quotes.

Comment: @Mikel: Still doesn't work, not that I didn't try it out... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dir in ./*/
do
  (cd $dir && hg status)
done
```

Comment: Won't it be possible with a one-liner using the `xargs` combination? If not, I'd appreciate if you could explain why my one liner doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: The xargs version doesn't work because it ends up giving the directories as multiple arguments to a single `hg` command; this answer issues multiple `hg` commands in different directories (oh, and use semicolons instead of newlines and that _is_ a one-liner!)

Comment: @Norman: Thanks for the clarification. But the question again is, why does `ls | xargs grep "something"` works but `ls | xargs hg status` doesn't?

Comment: @sasuke:  `grep` accepts multiple files as arguments while `hg status` does not.

Comment: But then what about `ls | xargs -t -I {} mv {} {}.old`? Anyways, I've found the solution and it is to explicitly use placeholders in `xargs`. Thanks for guiding me on the right way, I'll accept your answer since it also does what I was after. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `hg` allows running in parallel, you can use GNU Parallel

```
parallel cd {} '&&' hg status ::: ./*/
```

If not you can add -j1:

```
parallel -j1 cd {} '&&' hg status ::: ./*/
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ